# Тренечка или треничка?

Tags: орфография

Как пишется, иду на *тренечку* или *треничку*?

Comment: Никак не пишется. Слово не фиксируется словарями.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Надо ли уметь записывать слова, которые  не относятся к нормированной лексике?**  Думаю, что надо, тем более  что эта лексика  фиксируется **специальными словарями**, например:

1) Словарь ненормативной лексики (2002): ТРЕНИКИ (прост.) – штаны спортивного тренировочного костюма: «…стараниями внешторговского дяди одет он был всегда изрядно, даже под брюками вморозы носил не темно-синие треники, как мы, г решные…» (Поляков Ю. М.).

2) Толковый словарь русского школьного и студенческого жаргона (2005): Тренчик, тренька  (шутл.) – тренировка. Кто за час до игры такой мощный тренчик устраиает? Физручка Машку назначила треньку проводить.

**Итак, тренироваться** – трен/чик,  трен/ик (м.р.), трень/к/а, трен/ечк/а и трен/ичк/а (ж.р.) – **слово ищет подходящую форму.**

**Суффикса ЧЕК**  в языке не существует, **суффикс ЕК** содержит беглую гласную, а вот над выбором **ЕЧК/ИЧК** стоит задуматься:  Оля – Олечка, няня – нянечка,  доска –дощечка, книга – книжечка, время – времечко но: сестра – сестр/иц/а – сестр/ич/к/а, географ – географ/ичк/а (разг.).

Суффикс ЕЧК  имеет  ум.-ласк. значение и   используется для образования сущ. ж. и ср. рода , а суффикс ИЧК  имеет значение  только ж. рода и соответствует разговорному стилю, при этом он всегда ударный.

**И вывод:** суффиксы ЕЧК/ИЧК в нормативной речи не используются для образования существительных от глаголов, а при образовании от других существительных  только модифицируют их значение (лица или предмета),  **поэтому подходящих образцов нет.**

**Тем не менее оба варианта используются  при записи разговорной речи.** Вариант ЕЧК поддерживается словообразовательной цепочкой  «тренировка - треня – тренька - тренечка», а вариант «треничка» сохраняет  букву  И  мотивирующего глагола: "Очень хочу сходить в зал, на любимую треничку - пробежаться километров этак десять".

Comment: А Вы не путаете не нормированную лексику с ненормативной? Беда в том, что словари, собираемые таким образом ни за что ответсвенности не несут. Может и треники, а у меня так на слуху "тренцы". Вот и разбирайся, какой там суффикс.

Comment: Дело даже не  словарях (они только фиксируют факты), а в том, что в молодежном сленге присутствуют эти слова, нравятся ли они нам или нет. (Убедиться в этом легко, достаточно воспользоваться Интернетом, так о какой ответственности словарей может идти речь).Тренировка - слово длинное, официальное, не эмоциональное, удобное для письменных текстов,   в современный разговорный стиль оно просто не вписывается, вот и начинаются поиски подходящего эквивалента.  И мне кажется, что оценка результата - это интересная лингвистическая задача.

Comment: Да мало ли что в каком сленге присутствует?! У меня сой молодежный сленг, у Васи Пупкина - свой. А кто-то вообще на смеси французского с нижегородским говорит. Нельзя правила распространять на каждый чих. На такие случае есть транскрипция. А если вы будете нормировать слово по факту появения его в чьей-то речи, то оно в серьезном текстье появится на том основании, что Вы дали ему право на жизнь. Нет, есть старое доброе правило, что написание некодифицированных слов тоже не кодифицируется. А вне этого поля можно спорить сколько угодно. Все равно - схоластика.

Comment: "А Вы не путаете ненормированную лексику с ненормативной"? (Это Ваши слова). Есть словари ненормативной лексики, они  просто записывают слова, но не нормируют их. Нормированная лексика - это та, которая одобрена официальными словарями, они уже указывают ненормированные ВАРИАНТЫ слов. Официальные словари не занимаются ненормативной лексикой.

Comment: "А Вы не путаете ненормированную лексику с ненормативной"? (Это Ваши слова). - мои. Но это единственное, что у Вас можно понять и принять. Остальное не имеет отношения ни ко мне, ни к теме вопроса. Даже не могу понять, что тут можно связать с общим правилом не говорить о каких-то правилах написания несуществующих в литературном языке слов.

Comment: В молодежной среде эти слова достаточно распространены, кажется,  даже есть песня "Треничка", вот люди и спрашивают, как правильно.писать (оба варианта встречаются). Я  (пользуясь толковым словарем словообразовательных единиц) даю оценку этих вариантов с точки зрения грамматики, и что вы видите в этом  предосудительного и неправильного?

Comment: Ну и что? Есть куда более распространенные сленговые слова,  правописании которых спорят, ну так они фиксируются - потому и спорят. А ваше мнение будет ктио-то всерьез рассматривать, если придет автор с другим мнением - и зафиксирует это в написании?! Вот объясните, почему "велик", но "телек"?

Answer (score 0):

По общему правилу:

> Суффикс **-ичк-** пишется, если имя существительное образовано от
>   слова с суффиксом **-иц-**: водичка (от водица), пуговичка (от
>   пуговица), лестничка (от лестница). Во всех остальных случаях пишется
>   **-ечк**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть и одно уточнение - об именах собственных и одушевлённых существительных:

[Правописание гласной в суффиксе -ичк-/-ечк-](http://school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore-wrapper/21ebcc42-0627-448a-b62f-c39d0af8b883/sheg11_4.htm)

> зависит от образования слова: если оно образовано от слова с суффиксом
>   -иц- или от одушевленного существительного мужского рода, мужского или женского имени с суффиксом -ик-, то пишется и (пуговичка от пуговица;
>   котичка от котик; Эдичка от Эдик, Вероничка от Вероника); если нет, то
>   пишется е (имечко от имя, пышечка от пышка, Ванечка от Ваня).
>
> Следует запомнить как устарелое написание имени **Феничка** у
>   Тургенева.

Comment: Поскольку неясео, от какого слова образовано, неизвестно и что здесь суффикс. Это первое. Второе, приучать к "правописанию" неизвестных науке слов - дело крайне неблагодарное. На такие окказионализмы не распространяются правила вообще, а слово как бы реабилитируется.

Comment: Теперь по источнику. Непонятно кто непонятно что выдал. Интересно, а чем мотивируется то, что из всех известных случаев написания имен через ичк вопреки современным правилам авторы вспомнили одну Феничку?  На самом дели варианты Вадинька, Валичка, Сашинька постоянны в текстах личного (и не только) авторов XVIII-XIX веков. Это было нормой, если не правилом. Тургенев просто зафиксировал современную её орфографию. И если бы только он...

Comment: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions - подробности некоторые.

Comment: Устарело не у Тургенева, а сейчас эти формы устарелые. Мотивируется это тем, что в русском языке нет безударного суффикса ячк.

Comment: *Устарело не у Тургенева, а сейчас эти формы устарелые* - это как? Почему "не у Тургенева"? ***Устарело то, что написано у Тургенева*** - в чем тут сложность для Вашего понимания?

Comment: Вот именно. То, что написано у Тургенева, ***сегодня устарело***. Это не значит, что ***устарело во времена Тургенева!***

Comment: Серж, не фантазируйте. Все было бы ничего, но ваша придирка "устарело не у Тургенева" - не к месту. А объяснять мне ничего не надо. Я прекрасно поняла, что Вы не разобрались в конструкции "устарело [тл, что] Тугенева", решив, что это, дескать, уже во времена Тургенева было старым. Но такая трактовка никому бы в голову не пришла, кроме вас.